# compare urls and find duplicates in python

Tags: python, string, comparison

I am writing a code. I have two separate lists of urls. I want to compare the urls from list 1 with list 2 and find which urls from list 1 are already there in list 2. I am coding in python.

Comment: Set intersection? `result = set(list1).intersection(set(list2))` or something similar perhaps?

Comment: see RFC 3986 section 6.1

Answer (score 0):

I know I commented but it seems like you are looking for a [Set intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)). You want the URLs that are common between both lists.

```
list1 = ["some_url", "another_url", "some_other_url"]
list2 = ["another_url", "some_different_url"]
result = set(list1).intersection(set(list2)) # { "another_url" }
```